Unable to rotate screen using xrandr with VMware SVGA II adapter on SUSE Linux
I am using a SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop in a virtual environment with a VMware SVGA II Adapter. I need to rotate my screens using xrandr, but every time I try to do so, I get the following error:
xrandr: output Virtual1 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"

Here is some relevant information about my setup:

Graphics Adapter: VMware SVGA II Adapter (driver: vmwgfx)
Display Server: X11 (X.Org version 1.21.1.4)
Driver: vmwgfx (OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 22.3.5)
VM Environment: VMware VDI

When I run inxi -G, it gives me:
Graphics:
  Device-1: VMware SVGA II Adapter driver: vmwgfx v: 2.20.0.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: gpu: vmwgfx note: X driver n/a - try sudo/root
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 22.3.5 renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)

What I’ve tried:

Using xrandr to rotate the screen (xrandr --output Virtual1 --rotate left)
Checked for any VMware or SUSE settings that might enable screen rotation

None of these have worked.
Is there any way to enable screen rotation using xrandr or another tool while using the VMware SVGA II Adapter in a VDI environment?
Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
